# Cloudflare - Do I still need to cache?

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I heard about cloudflare 5 min ago and it seems really good. I read that they can hold my website online even if my server is offline, so I guess they are caching my site.

So I am very new to web-development but I think my visitors will hit the cloudflare servers instead of my server. Is this correct?

(I am talking about newspages that are the same of everyone, not user specific dynamic content)

So I guess I wouldn't have to cache those "static" sites anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Cloud Flare Provides Is Just a picture of your website and some pages may not be available at the time your server is offline, and it's very similar to what Google does.

Comment: So I don't have to cache my newspage anymore because cloudflare already cached it for me?

Comment: @MaikKlein no i think you have to because I Think cloud flare cache the homepage only, but it's better to ask.

Comment: ah yeah I found an answer here http://support.cloudflare.com/kb/how-does-cloudflare-make-my-website-or-blog-faster/does-cloudflare-cache-html-content  Too bad this would have been so awesome.

Answer (score 0):

In fact CloudFlare can cache everything on your website. You'd have to force it by creating a 'Cache-everything' PageRule. For mostly static sites it's actually a quite a good idea.

Look up here for more details:
http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-advanced-caching